# Strange dependency inserted into package.json npm install

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I am building a project using npm 7.24.0 and running

```
npm install --lockfile-version 2 --legacy-peer-deps
```

When the project builds it inserts an extra line into `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "2": "^3.0.0",
```

Is this related to the lockfile version forcing or for some other reason?

Comment: `lockfile-version` isn't supported config in NPM 7: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config.

Answer (score 2):

Its because it's literally installing the dependency "2" as stated in your npm install command. It's installing this package for reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/2.